# Using time:go-until in NetLogo time extension

Tags: time, netlogo

Using the NetLogo time extension on NetLogo 5.1.0 and Windows 8.1, I would like a simulation to stop either at a specific date, or after a specific period of time.

`time:go-until` should work for this according to the documentation on https://github.com/colinsheppard/time/#discrete-event-scheduler, but I can't figure out how to use it correctly. Here's what I have so far:

```
extensions [time]

globals[
  start-time
  current-time
]

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks

  set start-time time:create "2011-01-01"
  set current-time time:anchor-to-ticks start-time 1.0 "days"
  time:anchor-schedule start-time 1.0 "days"

  create-turtles 2
  time:schedule-repeating-event-with-period turtles task [fd 1] 1 1.0 "days"
end

to go-until
  time:go-until 40
  ;time:go-until time:create "2011-03-01"
  ;time:go-until time:plus start-time 33.0 "days" 
end
```

Like this, the sim runs for 40 ticks and then ends as expected. However, when I replace `time:go-until 40` with either `time:go-until time:create "2011-03-01"` or `time:go-until time:plus start-time 33.0 "days"`, I get this error at the start of the  simulation:

```
Extension exception: time: was expecting a number as argument 1, found this instead: {{time:logotime 2011-03-01}}
error while observer running TIME:GO-UNTIL
called by procedure GO-UNTIL
called by Button 'go'
```

Here's an example from the documentation which should work correctly:

```
time:go-until time:plus t-datetime 1.0 "hour" 
;; Execute events within the next hour; t-datetime is the current time.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This has now been filed as an issue at https://github.com/colinsheppard/time/issues/35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of the `time` extension fixed the issue and `time:go-until` now works as intended when used with LogoTimes (see [here](https://github.com/colinsheppard/time/issues/35)).