# Discrete event scheduling in NetLogo: daily and monthly tasks

Tags: time, netlogo

This question is slightly related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25060039/using-timego-until-in-netlogo-time-extension) one.

Using the NetLogo time extension on NetLogo 5.1.0 and Windows 8.1, I would like my simulation to

- represent one day as one netlogo tick,
- do some daily tasks,
- do some monthly task on the first day of each month,
- (do some yearly and decadal tasks, but that's not relevant for this question).

According to the [time documentation](https://github.com/colinsheppard/time/), this should be possible:

> "So if you use the time:plus primitive to add 1 month to the date "2012-02-02", you will get "2012-  03-02"; and if you add another month you get "2012-04-02" even though February and March have different numbers of days."

However, in my minimal working example below, the output of the `print` command in the console is `2011 January 2`, `2011 February 2`, `2011 March 5` and `2011 April 5`.

So, how can I schedule a task on the some day each month?

Bonus question: How can I schedule the task in the first of each month (instead of the second)?

Here's the working example:

```
extensions [time]

globals[
  start-time
  current-time
]

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks

  set start-time time:create "2011-01-01"
  set current-time time:anchor-to-ticks start-time 1.0 "days"
  time:anchor-schedule start-time 1.0 "days"

  ;time:schedule-repeating-event-with-period "observer" task do-daily 1 1.0 "days"
  time:schedule-repeating-event-with-period "observer" task do-monthly 1 1 "months"
  go-until
end

to do-daily
 ; here are the daily tasks
end

to do-monthly
  ; here are the monthly tasks
 print time:show current-time "yyyy MMMM d"
end

to go-until
  time:go-until 100
end
```

Comment: Maybe report it at https://github.com/colinsheppard/time/issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug that has now been fixed. See:

https://github.com/colinsheppard/time/issues/34

Comment: Thanks! I just tested the new version and the rescheduling now works as intended.